# Typing an adjust function

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to setup a function which takes an index, a function, and an array, and returns a clone of the array, except with the item at the index specified adjusted using the function.

```js
const adjust = <T, U extends T[], V extends number>(index: V) =>
  (f: (x: U[V]) => U[V]) => (xs: T[]) =>
    Object.assign([], xs, { [index]: f(xs[index]) });
```

I would hope that this would return the type `U`, but it returns type:

```js
never[] & T[] & {
    [x: number]: U[V];
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this to return a more usable type?

Comment: Object.assign isn't what you want here from a type perspective. Try `[...xs.slice(index - 1), f(xs[index]), ...xs.slice(index + 1)]`. Alternatively, you can add add another overload to assign that understands arrays

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do what you want:

```js
function modifyItem<T>(array: T[], index: number, modifier: (item: T) => T): T[] {
  return array.map((item, i) => i === index ? modifier(item) : item);
}
```

Alternatively if you want to keep all the type information with tuples:

```js
function modifyItem<T extends unknown[], U extends keyof T>(array: T, index: U, modifier: (item: T[U]) => T[U]): T {
  const result = [...array] as T;
  result[index] = modifier(result[index]);
  return result;
}
```

More functional style version with currying:

```js
const modifyItem =
  <T extends unknown[]>(array: T) =>
  <U extends number>(index: U) =>
  (modifier: (item: T[U]) => T[U]) => [
    ...array.slice(0, index),
    modifier(array[index]),
    ...array.slice(index + 1)
  ] as T;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't understand why you need to split one transformation into three separate functions, it only complicates the whole solution. It could be:

```
function customClone<T>(array: T[], index: number, modifier: (elem: T) => T): T[] {
  const resultArray = array.slice();
  resultArray.splice(index, 1, modifier(array[index]));
  return resultArray;
}
```

Tip: Should be handled the case when the wrong `index` could be passed.

Comment: Could you explain how it complicates things? Currying is fairly common and makes my life a lot easier in the code I'm working with

Comment: Oh, currying! Now I'm understood why the code was written in this way.